# How to write values in csv based on quotation mark and ignore commas inside the quotation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I would like to write some items of a list in a csv, the items are within quotation marks and have commas in between. How can I write them so that the items are not separated due to commas? I looked at many questions that are similar but did not find particular solution to my problem.

```
['Saks, Lord & Taylor data breach may affect 5 million customers', (u'By Mike Murphy', u'April 1, 2018, 5:24 p.m. EST')]
['Why The China Hustle is a finance documentary all U.S. investors need to see', (u'By MarketWatch', u'NewsWatch')]
['Trump says no deal for Dreamers, again threatens to end Nafta in Easter tweets', (u'By Mike Murphy', u'April 1, 2018, 4:49 p.m. EST')]
```

Expected answer:

```
first column = 'Saks, Lord & Taylor data breach may affect 5 million customers'
                'Why The China Hustle is a finance documentary all U.S. investors need to see'
                'Trump says no deal for Dreamers, again threatens to end Nafta in Easter tweets'

second column = 'By Mike Murphy' 
                'By MarketWatch'
                'By Mike Murphy'

third column =  'April 1, 2018, 5:24 p.m. EST'
                'NewsWatch'
                'April 1, 2018, 4:49 p.m. EST'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
x=[['Saks, Lord & Taylor data breach may affect 5 million customers', (u'By                                                      Mike Murphy', u'April 1, 2018, 5:24 p.m. EST')],['Why The China Hustle is a finance documentary all U.S. investors need to see', (u'By MarketWatch', u'NewsWatch')],['Trump says no deal for Dreamers, again threatens to end Nafta in Easter tweets', (u'By Mike Murphy', u'April 1, 2018, 4:49 p.m. EST')]]
import csv
with open('bla.csv','w') as fd:
    writer=csv.writer(open('bla.csv','w'))
    writer.writerows(x)
```

Note "Why The China ..." is not quoted in the `csv` as it does not contain any commas. If you want it quoted you can use `quoting=QUOTE_ALL` in the `writer` constructor.

Comment: thank you. I could write it into two columns now I will try writing it into three columns.

Comment: @A.S that changes things a bit, you will need to split the strings you want separate.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
next_field<-function(stream) {
  p<-seek(stream)
  d<-readChar(stream,1)
  seek(stream,p)
  if(d=="\"")    
    field<-scan(stream,"",1,sep=",",quote="\"",blank=FALSE)   
  else
    field<-scan(stream,"",1,sep=",",quote="",blank=FALSE)
  return(field)
}


s<-file("C:/your_path_here/sample.csv",open="rt")
header<-readLines(s,1)
header<-scan(what="",text=header,sep=",")
line<-replicate(length(header),next_field(s))

setNames(as.data.frame(lapply(line,type.convert)),header)
```